# NixOS: adding underneath existing attrset

Tags: nix, nixos

I am writing a little email NixOS module, which sets up `mutt`, `mbsync`, `msmtp`, etc. for provided accounts. I want it to be declared for specific users, since created files should be owned by that user, and in XDG directories for that user. That is, something like (in `configuration.nix`):

```
users.extraUsers.me = {
  ...
  email = {
    enable = true;
    accounts = [{
      host = "mail.service.com";
      user = "me@service.com";
      ...}
      ...];
  }
}
```

I know how to create a service with a *specific* path (e.g., `services.email`). Bu the module needs to know what the user name is, and needs to fit inside *any* user. Is there a way of doing that - adding options to an existing attrsof? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to deploy mutt, mbsync, and the rest as systemd user services. Technically, you could use submodules to create a module schema similar to `users.users.<name>`, however since NixOS doesn't manage the users home directory you won't be able to place configuration files and create directories.

User service templates should solve your problem and you can still encapsulate them in your module

something like this:

```
config = {
  systemd.user.services."mutt@" = {
    # template unit declaration
    ...
  };
  ... 
}
```

This way you can use systemd's template features to get the current user and  their path if needed.